# unit test the code inside valuechanges of formgroup in angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I want to unit test the code inside a formgroup valuechanges as shown in the below. I have tried different methods like spy, fakeAsync etc. but none of them helps in achieving full code coverage.

```
this.partyForm.valueChanges.
pipe(distinctUntilChanged(), debounceTime(100), takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe))
    .subscribe((formValue) => {
        if (this.partyForm.enabled) {
            this.updateDateField(formValue);
        }
    }));
```

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of struggle I found a way to write a test case. posting it so it could help any one in some way.

```
it('should call updateDateField on partyForm value changes', fakeAsync(() => {
    const spy = spyOn(component, 'updateDateField').and.callThrough();
    component.partyForm.enable();
    component.partyForm.get('partyName').setValue('test');
    component.updateDateField({
        partyName: 'test'
    });
    tick(500);
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));
}));
```